# appending multiple elements in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a program which will collect student's name and marks and add them to the dictionary and if the student has secured a mark above 75 it will print its name.
Here is the code:

```
n = 2
b = {}
for i in range(n):
    x = input('name : ')
    y = int(input('marks '))
    b[x] = y

for student in b :
    if b[student] >= 75:
        print('got it ')
```

is there any elegant way of doing this and a simple one?

Comment: f-strings allow to insert content of a variable into a string easily.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to `print` the student's name? As @MichaelButscher has mentioned, you can use f-strings. For example: `print(f"{student} got it")`. Or, you can simply join them: `print(student + " got it")`.

Comment: no , i want to find how many of the students have scored above 75 and then print their names

Comment: @ganeshmurthy, I guess only my answer includes code to show the **number of students** who have gotten more than 75. My answer is short and simple, but if you want to use one-liners, see the other answers (but other answers don't have code to get the number of 75+ students). If you copy the third code block, don't forget to change the position of the `b[x] = y` line. Please see the latest edited version. There was a mistake when I edited it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 4  # I am taking 4 students in this example
b = {}
for i in range(n):
    x = input('name : ')
    y = int(input('marks '))
    b[x] = y
```

`b` is the dictionary with student names and marks:

Suppose you have 4 students with names and marks:

```
b={'John': 80, 'Shane': 70, 'Mark': 90, 'Steff': 78}
```

You can do :

```
for name,marks in b.items():
    if marks>75:
        print(name)

#output
John
Mark
Steff
```

Can also do in a single list comprehension:

```
[name for name,marks in b.items() if marks>75]
#['John', 'Mark', 'Steff']
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all `y = int(input('marks '))` will not work if you pass more than one mark.** I would suggest you decide if it will be passed with `,` or space as separator and change the first loop in this way:

```
for i in range(n):
    name = input('name ')
    marks = input('marks ').split('YOUR SEPARATOR')
    marks = [int(element) for element in marks]
    marks_sum = sum(y)
    b.update({name: marks_sum})
```

And later change a little bit the second loop if you want to specify which student scored more than 75:

```
good_students = 0
for student in b :
    if b[student] >= 75:
        print(f'{student} got it ')
        good_students += 1
print(f'{good_students} have scored 75 points or more.\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this using dictionary comprehensions:

```py
marks = {input("Name: ").capitalize(): int(input("Marks: ")) for _ in range(n)}
```

As for printing:

```py
for name, mark in marks.items():
    if mark>75:
        print(f"{name} got {mark} marks on the test!")
```

Or combine it into one list comprehension (not recommended, since it is more readable to do it the above way)

```py
[print(f"{name} got {mark} marks on the test!") for name, mark in marks.items() if mark>75]
```

That means you could either write it as

```py
marks = {input("Name: ").capitalize(): int(input("Marks: ")) for _ in range(n)}
for name, mark in marks.items():
    if mark>75:
        print(f"{name} got {mark} marks on the test!")
```

Or

```py
marks = {input("Name: ").capitalize(): int(input("Marks: ")) for _ in range(n)}
[print(f"{name} got {mark} marks on the test!") for name, mark in marks.items() if mark>75]
```

Now @Maciej Dałek had a good point. The current method does not allow more than one mark to be passed in at once. However, this can easily be fixed if we first modify our `marks` dictionary.

```py
marks = {input("Name: ").capitalize(): list(map(int, input("Marks: ").split(","))) for _ in range(n)}
```

This code, instead of just taking in a single input for Marks, allows the user to input something like Marks: 1, 54, 99, 24. All of the scores will then be stored within the dictionary as integers via the `map` function (i.e. `{"Joe": [1, 54, 99, 24]}` ).

Now we can input multiple marks for each person. Now with a little modification of our printing statement, we can accept multiple values for marks.

```py
minimum_marks = 75
for name, mark in marks.items():
    # Check if any of the marks are above minimum_marks
    if next((True for i in mark if i>minimum_marks), False):
        print(f"{name} got higher than {minimum_marks} on one of their tests!")
```

The `next()` method returns the next item in the generator sequence. The generator sequence checks if there are any scores above `minimum_marks`. If there are, then it will print their name.

So in conclusion, if there is only one input for `marks`, then you can use the above code. Otherwise, you can use the following code:

```py
minimum_marks, n = 75, 4
marks = {input("Name: ").capitalize(): list(map(int, input("Marks: ").split(","))) for _ in range(n)}
for name, mark in marks.items():
    # Check if any of the marks are above minimum_marks
    if next((True for i in mark if i>minimum_marks), False):
        print(f"{name} got higher than {minimum_marks} on one of their tests!")
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use ternary operator : It simply allows testing a condition in a single line replacing the multiline if-else making the code compact.
and you can unpack the dictionary you made insteade of using indexes in the loop

```
n = 2
b = {}
for i in range(n):
    x = input('name : ')
    y = int(input('marks '))
    b[x] = y

for name,mark in b.items() :
    print('got it ') if mark >= 75 else print("you failed")
```

check this link for more information
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-operator-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a line in the first `for` loop:

```py
n = 2
b = {}
for i in range(n):
    x = input('name : ')
    y = int(input('marks '))
    b[x] = y
    if y >= 75:
        #print(x + " got " + str(y))
        print(f"{x} got {y}") #the same as the previous line
```

If you want to store the marks of **only** students who have gotten more than 75, just change your code to do so:

```py
n = 2
b = {}
for i in range(n):
    x = input('name : ')
    y = int(input('marks '))
    if y >= 75:
        b[x] = y #store the marks only if the student has gotten more than 75
        #print(x + " got " + str(y))
        print(f"{x} got {y}")
```

I've reduced it to just 1 loop. It's short and simple, but if you want to use one-liners, see the other answers.

To find the **number of students** who have gotten more than 75, just create a variable and update it in the loop:

```py
n = 2
b = {}
m75 = 0

for i in range(n):
    x = input('name : ')
    y = int(input('marks '))
    if y >= 75:
        b[x] = y
        #print(x + " got " + str(y))
        print(f"{x} got {y}")
        m75 += 1 #m75 = m75 + 1 (increases m75 by 1)

print(m75)
```

Here, `m75` is the variable which stores how many students have gotten more than 75.

Note: if you copy the third code block (which uses the `m75` variable), don't forget to change the position of the `b[x] = y` line. If you want to store the marks of *only* the students who have gotten more than 75, then there's no need to change anything.
But if you want to store all the marks, copy the first code block and just create the `m75` variable and assign it `0`. Then just add the `if` from the third code block.